# Macro/VBA to Add Text to Column if there is text present in another cell

Tags: vba, macros

I have a report that I download. It has varying Column A lengths. I'm looking to create a VBA/Macro that will put a certain text in M2 if there is *any* data present in the corresponding A cell. I don't want it to put data in every cell in column M indefinitely, and only want it to put the text if there is something in the corresponding A cell.

I tried this but it isn't working:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("M2").Value = "Testing"
End If
End Sub
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What does "It isn't working" mean? Do you not get the results you're after? Are the results wrong? Please be as specific as you can be to get good help.

Answer (score 0):

The first code you tried checks one cell (A2) and fills one cell (M2). If you want to check more cells, then put a "For Each" loop in the macro. For an example, see [How To Repeat Tasks With Your VBA Code by Looping](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2015/4/9/repeat-tasks-with-vba-code-by-looping)

If you don't want to use a macro, you can use a [filter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-01832226-31b5-4568-8806-38c37dcc180e) to show only rows with values in column A.

Answer (score 0):

If you by "corresponding A cell" truly mean A2, and your code is correct, but is throwing errors when trying to run it, try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("A2").Value <> "" Then
    Range("M2").Value = "Testing"
End If
End Sub
```

I assume you put this code in the actual worksheet where you want it to run.

This will print "Testing" in "M2" each time the sheet is changed when there is something in "A2".

If you want that part automatically removed as well, you could add

```
Else
Range("M2").Value = ""
```

in the If.